# creating a tumblr theme - audio posts don't show on blog

Tags: css, audio, tumblr, posts

I'm creating a new tumblr theme (I'm almost finished actually). The only problem I'm running into (and I ran into the same problem on the last theme I made) is that no matter how I format an audio post, it will not show up on my blog. My formatted audio posts how up both on the dashboard, and on the customize theme page.

I saw that audio/video posts sometimes have a problem with infinite scroll, so I removed all of my scripts. Audio posts still don't show up.

This is the code I have for the audio post:

```
{block:Audio}

<div id="post">

{block:AudioPlayer}
<div id="audioplayer">
{AudioPlayerBlack}
</div>
{/block:AudioPlayer}

<div id="albumart">
{block:AlbumArt}
<img src="{AlbumArtURL}">
{/block:AlbumArt}
</div>

</div>         
{/block:Audio}
```

this is the css for those divs (in case that's the problem)

```
#post
{
float: left;
padding: 5px;
margin: 4px;
background-color: {color:Post Background};
width: 215px;
    -moz-border-radius: 7px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 7px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 7px;
    border-radius: 7px;
box-shadow: 2px 2px 4px {color:Post Shadow};
}


#albumart
{
margin: 3px;
margin-bottom: 2px;
width:207px;
height: 207px;
border: 1px solid {color:Border Color};
overflow: hidden;
}

#audioplayer
{
width:25px;
height:25px;
overflow:hidden;
position:absolute;
margin-top:100px;
margin-left:100px;
    -moz-border-radius: 18px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 18px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 18px;
    border-radius: 18px;
opacity:0.75;
border:5px solid black;
}
```

You can see it here: smash-howard.tumblr.com

Comment: Is it possible for you to add a audiopost to your tumblr so we can see what happens with it?

Comment: I have posted an audio post to my tumblr. It only shows up on my dash, it won't show up on my actual tumblr page and doesn't even show up in the page html (i just checked).. the problem is, that even when I post an audio post, it doesnt show up on my tumblr. I could give you the code, so that you can see that the audio DOES show up in the customize blog page...

Comment: customization page: http://i45.tinypic.com/2150xf8.png  // dashboard: http://i46.tinypic.com/2hyx91f.png    -- see? there's an audio post there. it's somehow not making it to the tumblog page.

Comment: Hah. Found the block:AudioPlayer now. Must have been blind. Anyhow, just to check: Is it between `{block:Posts}{/block:Posts}`?

Comment: yep, I just figured out that I left out the {AudioEmbed-250} because i'm an airhead. :] However, the embedded audio player was about 50px wider than my post, but I got to show up and not stretch out the page. So it's not as pretty as it could be, but it works now! :]

Comment: Hurrah! Add it as an answer to your question when you can. Then select it as the correct answer aswell. Just to make the question be closed properly.

Answer (score 0):

Since this hasn't been updated with answer and I had a similar problem, here's what needed to be done:

```
{block:Posts}
...

{block:Audio}
    {block:AudioEmbed}
    <div class="audio-embed">
        {AudioEmbed-400}
    </div>
    {/block:AudioEmbed}
    {block:AudioPlayer}
    <div class="audio-player">
        {AudioPlayerBlack}
    </div>
    {/block:AudioPlayer}
{/block:Audio}

...
{/block:Posts}
```

This way you're accounting for both possible audio post scenarios: audio embed and the audio player. Only accounting for one will cause the other to not show, which is what was happening in this case.